# An orthonormal system is total if and only if

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over a field $\mathbb K$.

> Prove that an orthonormal system $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $H$ is total if and only if: $\forall$ $x \in H$, the following holds:
>
> $(\forall n \in \mathbb N)(<x,a_n> = 0) \iff x = 0$

Here is the (textbook) solution:

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a total orthonormal system and $Y$ be the subspace generated by $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, then $Y$ is dense in $H$. Let $x \in H$, then $x \in \bar Y$. Put $c_n = <x,a_n>$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$. For $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $m \in \mathbb N$ such that:

$$||x - \sum_{p=1}^n c_p a_p|| < \epsilon, \forall \ n \ge m \cdots (\star)$$

Afterwards everything is completely fine. However, I could not see why $(\star)$ holds. I understand that the denseness of $Y$ has to do with it. But why are the $c_p$'s involved, and not some arbitrary constants $k_p$'s?

Can anyone explain to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the system is orthonormal the Fourier coefficients are the coefficients of the best approximation. If $k_1,\ldots k_n$ are any scalars in $\mathbb K$ then necessarily
$$\left\| x - \sum_{p=1}^n c_p a_p \right\| \le \left\| x - \sum_{p=1}^n k_p a_p \right\|.$$
Thus if *some* linear combination of the $a_p$'s is close to $x$, so is its best approximation.